# How to write multiple HTML tags to a list which have different attributes using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am quite new to collecting data from HTML, and although I did read the documentation, I was not able to find a conclusive answer to the following question: I want to gather similar tags which have different attributes. What I am doing currently works, but it feels like there must be a more elegant solution.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html_doc ="""
<html><div class="cf result lastresult" id="3" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Test"></div>
<div class="cf result" id="1" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Test2"></div>
<div class="cf result" id="2" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Test"></div></html>"""
soup_doc = soup(html_doc, 'lxml')
```

I want to gather all three div classes, however, one has a different name (cf result lastresult).

Current solution:

```
Item_list=[]
for i in soup_doc.find_all("div",{"class":("cf result lastresult" )}):
    Item_list.append(i)
for i in soup_doc.find_all("div",{"class":("cf result")}):
    Item_list.append(i)
```

This results in the desired outcome:

```
[<div class="cf result lastresult" id="3" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Test"></div>,
 <div class="cf result" id="1" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Test2"></div>,
 <div class="cf result" id="2" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Test"></div>]
```

I have tried several other options which seemed more logical but did not work such as:

```
Item_list=soup_doc.find_all("div",{"class":("cf result" or "lastresult" )})

Item_list=soup_doc.find_all("div",{"class":("cf result" )}).append(soup_doc.find_all("div",{"class":("cf result lastresult" )}))
```

Any solutions to make the code shorter or faster are welcome.

Comment: Maybe `soup_doc.select('div.cf.result')` (to take all divs that have both cf and result and any other classes...)?

Comment: This works as a charm! Thanks.